# Does cpp_dec_float give consistent results across platforms?

Tags: c++, math, boost, floating-point

Can a custom number type such as cpp_dec_float (from Boost) guarantee a consistent floating-point arithmetic behavior (on trigonometric functions such as cos, sin, tan, atan) across different system architectures / devices?

Comment: Are you asking about the specific Boost implementation, or the general principle? Because computers are deterministic, so the obvious answer is yes. Floating point is not magic.

Comment: I think you mean "consistency", not "determinism". Floating point operations are already deterministic across platforms, in the sense that a given platform will always give the same answer given the same input; but they are not consistent, in the sense that different platforms may give different answers with the same input.

Comment: yes, sorry I meant consistency

Comment: @Sneftel if you have sources to back up the second part of your second sentence, I think that it should be an answer.

Comment: Platforms using IEEE-754 (basically this is true for all wide-spread, generally available CPUs) *can* guarantee consistent results. If a function use basic operations (+, -, *, /, sqrt), then the output will be the same.

Comment: @Fureeish The OP already knows about FP inconsistency. The question is whether this specific FP implementation inherits any potentially-inconsistent FP behavior from the architecture, and I don't know the answer.

Comment: @geza The OP is specifically asking about trig functions which IEEE-754 doesn't mandate precision for.

Comment: Could you clarify whether this is about `cpp_dec_float` in particular or about floating point consistency in general? Right now this is hard to answer because you could write custom, consistent trigonometric functions for virtually any numeric type...

Comment: @Sneftel: Sure. I meant, that if functions (trigonometric or not) use basic operations to calculate the result (which is usually the case today), the output will be consistent (the algorithm needs to be the same as well, of course).

Comment: I mentioned in the description "custom number type" such as cpp_dec_float, because I know it has its own implementation of several generic mathematical functions. I looked into the source code and it seems to be implementing some based on Taylor's approximation, which uses logs and eventually simple arithmetics that could potentially make it consistent but I am not 100% sure, so that's why I am asking this. In short, yes specifically to cpp_dec_float.

Comment: If you get a negative answer, then maybe it's worth checking out [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/).

Comment: There are multiple backends to cpp_dec_float. Since all the ops for the default Boost backend are done in software, then I imagine it would be. If you choose the MPFR backend, then you'd have to consult the MPFR docs.